# docker python3.x-minimal error after ubuntu update

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

my app working fine. now i want migrate my server to new EC2 from ubuntu 20 to 22.

this problem not only on new ubuntu (22) but also on 20 after ubuntu auto update.

this is my docker compose

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.13-slim as builder

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y build-essential gcc python3-dev musl-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev postgresql-server-dev-all cargo git tk libmagic1 

# lint

RUN pip install filemagic
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install flake8
COPY . /usr/src/app/


# install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install wheel
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt


#########
# FINAL #
#########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.13-slim

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# create the app user
# RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app
RUN adduser --system --group app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/staticfiles
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install dependencies
RUN apt update && apt install -y tk
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh $APP_HOME

# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

RUN chmod +x $APP_HOME/entrypoint.sh

# change to the app user
USER app

# run entrypoint.prod.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/web/entrypoint.sh"]
```

and this is the error

#0 26.68 P

```
reparing to unpack .../libpython3.9-minimal_3.9.2-1_amd64.deb ...
#0 26.70 Unpacking libpython3.9-minimal:amd64 (3.9.2-1) ...
#0 27.21 Selecting previously unselected package python3.9-minimal.
#0 27.21 Preparing to unpack .../python3.9-minimal_3.9.2-1_amd64.deb ...
#0 27.23 Unpacking python3.9-minimal (3.9.2-1) ...
#0 27.79 Setting up libpython3.9-minimal:amd64 (3.9.2-1) ...
#0 27.82 Setting up python3.9-minimal (3.9.2-1) ...
#0 28.16 Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 28.17   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/py_compile.py", line 215, in <module>
#0 28.17     sys.exit(main())
#0 28.17   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/py_compile.py", line 207, in main
#0 28.17     compile(filename, doraise=True)
#0 28.17   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/py_compile.py", line 172, in compile
#0 28.17     importlib._bootstrap_external._write_atomic(cfile, bytecode, mode)
#0 28.17   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 126, in _write_atomic
#0 28.18 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.9/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-39.pyc.140199513461120'
#0 28.18 dpkg: error processing package python3.9-minimal (--configure):
#0 28.18  installed python3.9-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
#0 28.21 Errors were encountered while processing:
#0 28.21  python3.9-minimal
#0 28.37 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt update     && apt install -y build-essential gcc python3-dev musl-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev postgresql-server-dev-all cargo git tk libmagic1]: exit code: 100
service "web" is not running container #1
```

already tried update the python slim from 3.9 to 3.10.x 3.1.x the problem still exist

Answer (score 0):

the problem only because i install docker using snap,
remove docker, install again using get-apt it solved